# Detect hand width and dynamically resize projected AR model

Tags: android, augmented-reality

I'm working on a project that detects the width of the human hand and projects a 3D model of a wristwatch on the hand using Augmented Reality application.
How do I find the width of the hand to change the dimensions of the wristwatch dynamically?

Comment: Ask the user to enter the value, create some kind of sensor, or get the user to take a picture of their hand, and delve into the field of image analysis.

Comment: How are you detecting the hand? Depending on the technology / library, you should have the means to get the contour dimensions...

Comment: @yakobom I'm planning on using OpenCV. The hand detection is to be done through an android application.